# libutils for android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to use some classes (Vector, string8) provided in the `libUtils.so`, but this library did not come with the `ndk_linux_x86_r4`. In addition, I am having some problems to build this library from the source code. Does anyone have this library built or know where to download it?

Comment: Where did this library come from?

Comment: @ognian, it resides in /android/frameworks/base/libs/utils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the Android source tree and the binary will appear in `out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/LINKED`.

Comment: You need to make sure this doesn't depend on other non-public library APIs, as if it does you may end up with an .apk that breaks on future android versions with different private api details.

Comment: There is no guarantee it'll work with past or future versions, but there's no need to point that out because it is clear for the fact it's missing from the NDK.

Comment: Is there any other library in the Android NDK that provides the same functionality. Because it fails the main purpose of providing using the NDK if one has to manually get the libutils package for each android version.