# Not able to run dumpsys.cpp from jni

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I was trying to run dumpsys.cpp in android ndk using JNI interface i got the source code of dumpsys from the following link
http://source-android.frandroid.com/frameworks/base/cmds/dumpsys/dumpsys.cpp.When i run the code i am getting following errors:-

```
error: utils/Log.h: No such file or directory
error: binder/Parcel.h: No such file or directory
error: binder/ProcessState.h: No such file or directory
error: binder/IServiceManager.h: No such file or directory
error: utils/TextOutput.h: No such file or directory
error: utils/Vector.h: No such file or directory
```

How should i remove them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365184/libutils-for-android-ndk