# Android development: updating code to more recent NDK?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have a problem with some code that has been written for Android NDK 10d. It's not my code, but I'd like to fork and recompile this project. But I run into problems with the current NDK (19c). I have seen the code snippet in other projects as well, but I couldn't find a proper way to update this section. Maybe someone here has an idea or could explain what the problem is exactly?

Code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_jackpal_androidterm_TermExec_createSubprocessInternal(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
    jstring cmd, jobjectArray args, jobjectArray envVars, jint masterFd)
{
    const jchar* str = cmd ? env->GetStringCritical(cmd, 0) : 0;
    String8 cmd_8;
    if (str) {
        cmd_8.set(str, env->GetStringLength(cmd));
        env->ReleaseStringCritical(cmd, str);
    }

...

    int ptm = create_subprocess(env, cmd_8.string(), argv, envp, masterFd);

return ptm;
}
```

I get the following error (referring to `cmd_8.set(str, env->GetStringLength(cmd));`):

```
process.cpp:210:19: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char16_t *' with an lvalue of type 'const jchar *' (aka 'const unsigned short *')
        cmd_8.set(str, env->GetStringLength(cmd));
                  ^~~
```

So I guess parameter types changed with newer versions of NDK? Do I need a type conversion somewhere? I guess there are just updated functions/calls to this in newer versions, but I couldn't find any documentation (also didn't know what to look for).

Any ideas?

Comment: `String8` is an internal (part of the Android Platform), not a public part of the NDK see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365184/libutils-for-android-ndk

Comment: But how come I didn't have to build Android source on older ndk versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler in r19 is less forgiving than the one from r10. The parameter types did not change, but the recent **clang** requires that you add explicit cast:

```
 cmd_8.set((const char16_t*)str, env->GetStringLength(cmd));
```

This said, your project may have a worse problem, as [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444702/android-development-updating-code-to-more-recent-ndk#comment97605145_55444702) [@Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten). If it relies upon **libutils** and other Android private libraries, it will not work on Android Marshmallow and higher.

Comment: But if I build it with r10 (also r16 worked) it will run on Marshmallow?

Comment: That's weird. I compiled a version with r10 and I could run it on Pie.

Comment: As I wrote, ***if** it relies on private libraries*

Comment: Doesn't the use of "String8" imply it is relying on libutils and therefor should not work?

Comment: If your project copied the sources from Google, this can still work. The problems begin when it tries to load system libraries, **libutils** or other otehr, like **libbinder** that uses classes like **String8** extensively. Note that the original **String8** does not have a **set()** at all!